# Можно ли обработать обрыв выполения программы, вызванный по внешнему сигналу?

Tags: c++, windows, исключения

Допустим, есть консольная программа, внутри которой крутится бесконечный цикл, чтобы его остановить жмем клавиши <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> и обрываем этот цикл. А как сделать чтобы после этой комбинации выполнился некий код внутри этой программы? Может существует какое-либо исключение для этой операции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уот так уот:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

BOOL CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) 
{ 
  switch( fdwCtrlType ) 
  { 
    // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
    case CTRL_C_EVENT: 
      printf( "Ctrl-C event\n\n" );
      Beep( 750, 300 ); 
      return( TRUE );

    // CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit. 
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT: 
      Beep( 600, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Close event\n\n" );
      return( TRUE ); 

    // Pass other signals to the next handler. 
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: 
      Beep( 900, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Break event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: 
      Beep( 1000, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Logoff event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: 
      Beep( 750, 500 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Shutdown event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    default: 
      return FALSE; 
  } 
} 

int main( void ) 
{ 
  if( SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) ) 
  { 
    printf( "\nThe Control Handler is installed.\n" ); 
    printf( "\n -- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or" ); 
    printf( "\n    try logging off or closing the console...\n" ); 
    printf( "\n(...waiting in a loop for events...)\n\n" ); 

    while( 1 ){ } 
  } 
  else 
  {
    printf( "\nERROR: Could not set control handler"); 
    return 1;
  }
return 0;
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms685049(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: просто супер, большое спасибо

Comment: А `signal` не более стандартный способ?...

Comment: @Harry можно конечно и signal.h подключить но в чем будет выигрыш?

Comment: @perfect В стандарте

Comment: @Harry разве стандарт взятый из POSIX распространяется на windows системы?

Comment: @perfect А почему нет?

Comment: @Harry , ну хотябы потому что сигналы это механизм POSIX, а механизм WINSOWS это сообщения.